# Memory Leaks in RecyclerView when used in Fragment by LeakCanary

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-recyclerview, leakcanary

A simple application with *recyclerview* in fragment has memory leak as per leaks app.

[Memory Leak snapshot by Leak App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z9lY.png)

Stack of the Leak:

HelloTest.java:

```
public class HelloTest extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TestFrag mFrag = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mFrag = new TestFrag();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(android.R.id.content, mFrag )
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        RefWatcher refWatcher = AppClass.getRefWatcher(this);
        refWatcher.watch(this);

    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class TestFrag extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_hello_test, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/comme_rv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

By executing the above app code memory leak occurs when the app exits.
If same code is placed in activity instead of fragment then there is no leak.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create anything in the onDestroy method. So you put your code like this:

> ```
> public class HelloTest extends AppCompatActivity {
>     private TestFrag mFrag = null;
>    RefWatcher refWatcher;
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>         refWatcher = AppClass.getRefWatcher(this);
>         refWatcher.watch(this);
>         if (savedInstanceState == null) {
>             mFrag = new TestFrag();
>             getSupportFragmentManager()
>                     .beginTransaction()
>                     .replace(android.R.id.content, mFrag )
>                     .commit();
>         }
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onDestroy() {
>
>         if(refWatcher!=null){
>           // destroy refWatcher
>         }
>         super.onDestroy();
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have tired this but the issue is still there.

Comment: Please, put your code you have tried with onDestroy.
Try this :

public void onBackPressed() {
   if(refWatcher!==null){
          // destroy refWatcher
        }
   super.onBackPressed();}

Comment: I have removed onDestroy method. Still the issue exists

Comment: Can you upload your code to Github? ...I will check it.